# How do I load and parse a Json in isolate?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to load my json and parse it in a new isolate. If I understood correctly this allows better performance of the application.

I charge my json and parse it after my future builder.
I would like to parse it before in an isolate and return them all but I can't display my json.

Is this the right method or it's useless ?

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> loadJson() async {
  /*
  * I load my Json without other isolate and I parse it in the future builder
  */
  final myJson = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/jsons/myJson.json');

  return {
    'myJson' : myJson
  };
}

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> loadJsonParsed() async {
  /*
  * I load my Json and parse it in other isolate
  */
  final myJson = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/jsons/myJson.json');
  var myJsonParsed = compute(_parseJson, myJson);

  return {
    'myJson' : myJsonParsed
  };
}
Map<String, dynamic>_parseJson(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody);
  return parsed;
}

// Some code ...

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (() => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode())),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: Future.wait([loadJson(), loadJsonParsed()]),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return LinearProgressIndicator();
            }

            print('BEGIN ================================');
            var myJson = json.decode(snapshot.data[0]['myJson']);
            print(myJson); // I see my json !
            print(myJson.runtimeType); // _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>
            print('SEPARATION ================================');
            var myJsonParsed = snapshot.data[1]['myJson'];
            print(myJsonParsed); // Instance of 'Future<Map<String,dynamic>>' How to do ?
            print(myJsonParsed.runtimeType); // Future<Map<String,dynamic>>
            print('END ================================');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the json is small, probably it's not worth to move the parsing to a different isolate as this operation also has a cost. Small / big is something subjetive but using common sense we could likely apply the correct approach.

If the json is big, definitively you're doing the correct thing as otherwise dart would execute the parsing on the main thread, what could cause a visible jank.

In relation to why [`compute`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html) is working wrong for you, this function returns a `Future` so instead of doing this

```
var myJsonParsed = compute(_parseJson, myJson);
```

You need to await the call to get the result, otherwise you'll be storing a future here `'myJson' : myJsonParsed` and not the `json` map

```
var myJsonParsed = await compute(_parseJson, myJson);
```

Comment: I appreciate your help ! I understand thank you for your time.